# Can I edit the binlog retention period on just one replica?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Can I just set the binlog retention period for the final replica in my chain differently than it is for all the others? It is set at a week for all replicas but for the one I am using I need it to be set at one month or maybe longer. I can't do this on the other ones due to disk constraints. Thank you in advance. We are using MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the Question correctly, the short Answer is "yes".

Long Answer:

Each server has (optionally) its own binlogs, hence the various settings (retention, max_size) can be set independently.

Each *Replica* reads from the binlogs *of its Primary*.  The Replica has no control of those settings.

The idea is that a Primary (including a Replica that acts as a Primary to a downstream Replica) controls how long to hang onto the data before deciding that a Replica is gone and will never come back.

Each binlog has "equivalent" data but they are *not* interchangeable.  They are "rotated" independently; the messages in them may be in a different order.

Or, with binlog/replicate_do/ignore, the binlogs may not have the same set of data and could be quite different in size.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure I follow. If I have a source that cannot increase binlog retention period over 7 days, can I set the replica (which is at the end of the chain and has no replicas of its own) to keep the logs for 14 days?

Comment: @CClarke - As long as no one in the chain is offline for more than 7 days, the last one in the chain will receive all the data and can write it to as many binlog files as necessary.  What do you hope that this configuration will provide?  Binlogs, yes, but what might you be able to get from them?

Comment: We are trying to replicate into BigQuery and Google's datastream requires row-based binlogs for this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: ROW is probably the default in 5.7.  Is that an issue?